# Having trouble blitting freetype glyph buffers

Tags: c++11, visual-c++, directx-11, direct3d, freetype2

I'm having trouble stitching together glyphs created by freetype. Works perfectly using freeimage, but I don't want to include a huge library just for a small portion of it.

The full code is on github https://github.com/live627/Engine/blob/master/Engine/Engine/fontmanager.cpp#L171

I allocate the buffer

```
unsigned char * charmap = new unsigned char[m_width * m_height]();
```

I blit pixel buffers like this and get access violations

```
void Font::StitchGlyph(const GlyphInfo g,
    unsigned int px, unsigned int py, unsigned int total_width,
    unsigned int max_height, unsigned char * charmap)
{
    auto WIDTH = total_width, HEIGHT = max_height;

    for (int y = 0; y < g.bh; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < g.bw; x++)
        {
            //if (x >= WIDTH || y >= HEIGHT)
            //  continue; 

            charmap[(py + y) * WIDTH + (px + x)] = g.img[y * g.bw + x];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd verify in code that your offsets combined with the glyph width and height do not exceed the allocated bounds. So check

```
if (px + GlyphInfo.bw > m_width || py + GlyphInfo.bh > m_height) 
    // error
```

My guess is that's where it's coming from.

Comment: That stopped the buffer overflow, but now it renders (structured) garbage https://raw.githubusercontent.com/live627/Engine/master/Engine/Engine/garbage.bmp whereas the expected output is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/live627/Engine/master/Engine/Engine/charmap.bmp

Comment: It looks like it's being flipped vertically. Are there any negative numbers in the GlyphInfo data?

Comment: No, not that I can see, unless I'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I fixed it by using a vector for glyph buffer data.